comments are being saved in database to related post but not accessed in template even variable is correct
comments are being saved in database to related post but not accessed in template even variable is correct on debuging it shows the comment to realted post but not fetching it to the template only commet.count function showing one comment here is template
  <div class="comments">
                <h5 class="comment-title py-4">{{ comment.count }}</h5>
                
                
                {% for comment in comment5 %}
                <div class="comment d-flex mb-4">
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                        <div class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle">
                            <img class="avatar-img" src="{% static 'assets/img/person-5.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-2 ms-sm-3">
                        <div class="comment-meta d-flex align-items-baseline">
                            <h6 class="me-2"> {{comment.user}}</h6>
                            <span class="text-muted">{{comment.datetime}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                            {{comment.content}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               {% endfor %}
            </div><!-- End Comments -->

def blogpost1(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)  
    comment5=Comment.objects.filter(blog=post)

    print(f"Post: {post}")
    print(f"Comments: {comment5}")  # Debugging statement
    for comment in comment5:
        print(comment.id, comment.user, comment.content)
    print(comment5)
    if request.method=='POST':
        user = request.user
        content=request.POST.get('content')
        comment=Comment(user=user,content=content,blog=post)  
        comment.save()
    return render(request,'singlpost.html',{'post':post,'comment':comment5})



In your view you pass the list of comments as comment. When using it in the forloop, you should use {% for c in comment %}, without the 5.
